# Count number of objects created in C++

Tags: c++

Need to count no. of objects created in setval. Please help. 
Source Code : https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6igpioidhov9oo/static.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

class student
{
    static int count;
protected:
    char name[20];
    char course[20];
    int roll;
    float fees;
public:
    student()
    {
    }

    void setval()
    {
        count++;
        cout<<"\nEnter the name : ";
        cin>>name;
        /*cout<<"\nEnter the course : ";
         cin>>course;
         cout<<"\nEnter the roll : ";
         cin>>roll;
         */cout<<"\nEnter the fees : ";
        cin>>fees;
    }

    friend float calfeespaid(student);

    void showval()
    {
        cout<<"\nName = "<<name;
        //cout<<"\nCourse = "<<course;
        //cout<<"\nRoll = "<<roll;
        cout<<"\nfees = "<<fees;
        //cout<<"\nNo. of objects created : "<<count;
    }
};

float calfeespaid(student s)
{
    static float total;
    total=total+s.fees;
    return total;
}

main()
{
    student s[5],a;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) 
    { 
        s[i].setval(); 
        calfeespaid(s[i]); 
    }

    for( int i=0;i<3;i++) 
    { 
        //cout<<count; 
        s[i].showval(); 
    } 
    cout<<"\nTotal Fees Paid : "<<calfeespaid(a); 
    getch(); 
}
```

We have 3 member functions of the class student :
1. setval : To take input
2. showval : To display output
3. calfeespaid : To calculate total amount of fees paid

Now, my aim is to create a static int variable count which will count the number of objects created in the setval function.

Comment: Wait, so, you want me to help you fix your keyboard?

Comment: Here's my present for your: " ". Feel free to copy paste this space where ever you want. I recommend using it for indentation.

Comment: Want something from us? More effort required. Please do. How to: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Tried pasting the source code but lot of formatting errors

Comment: @SrijitB: The lack of source code is not the main issue here. You need to explain _what_ you've tried, _what_ went wrong and _why_ you expected a different result.

Comment: The objects are created with the constructor, setval only set new values for it. So.. you need to place count++ inside the constructor. And you need to initialize to 0 count outside the class definition

Answer (score 3):

0, no object created ..........

Comment: +1, completely accurate (I pasted the code into the question). There are no objects created in `setval()`

Comment: lol...........................